# Print specific Permutations of a list in Python

Tags: python, permutation

For all the permutations of a list, I want to print only those permutations in which the value at a particular index is greater than the values at previous indexes. Such an index would be called a "great index"
ex: If the list is `[1,2,3]`, its permutations are

```
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

I would like to print only such permutations in which there are only n "great indices". Let's say n=2, then the output would be:

```
[1,3,2],[2,1,3] and [2,3,1]
```

In `[1,3,2]`, indices 0 and 1 are great indices because 1(at index 0) does not have any previous elements and 3(at index 1) is greater than its previous element i.e 1. 2(at index 2) is not a "great index" because it is not greater than its previous element 3.
Similarly,
In `[2,1,3]`, indices 0 and 2 are great indices.
In `[2,3,1]`, indices 0 and 1 are great indices.
I'm using the permutations library in Python to generate the permutations. A simple, easy to understand solution would be appreciated.

Comment: A "great index" is a value that is larger than its index?

Comment: A "great index"  is an index whose element is greater than the elements at preceding indices.

Comment: So a great index is a "the greater so far" value? And first element is always considered as great?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried anything yourself to achieve this? Can you share this with us? Are there specific problems you are having with getting your code working?  We'd like to help you to be a better programmer rather than just doing work for you. The aim of this forum is not to write code for people, but rather to help discuss specific coding issues and aid the asker and those who come along later with a better understanding of the languages and tools involved.

Comment: @Steve, I just generated the permutations and tried using loops to iterate through the elements but got stuck there. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import itertools
def great(l, n): #function that counts the permutations of list l with n great indices
    def count_of_great(k): #function that counts the great indices of list k
        c=1 #because first element is always great
        for i in range(1,len(k)):
            if k[i]>max(k[:i]): #if the value is greater than all previous values we increase c
                c+=1
        return c #this is the count of great indices in k
    return [p for p in itertools.permutations(l) if count_of_great(p)==n] #this is a list of permutations of l that have a count_of_great eual with n

great([1,2,3], 2)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1)]
```

Comment: I understand a little of it, and I'm not good at Python one liners. Would you please explain the logic or add comments so I know how it works? Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I added some comments, i hope they help

Comment: Thanks a ton! :)